# No of different ways of marks can be obtained in MCQ?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

No of different possible marks we can get if 'a' marks will be added for the correct answer and 'b' marks will be deducted if the answer happened to be wrong. An unattempted question is awarded 0 marks.
The number of questions will be n.

For example:
For n=2 and a=1 and b=1 is -2,-1,0,1,2.
I have read this link.
[Possible marks in a MCQ test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710881/possible-marks-in-a-mcq-test)

Comment: The answer will depend on the number of questions on the test, which you have left unstated.

Comment: Number of questions will be n.

Comment: Knock Knock.....

Comment: @SagarSharma do you mean the no of different marks or the possible marks?

Comment: @SagarSharma Yes for?

Comment: No of possible marks that can be obtained by the student.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the total number of correct answers. You've mentioned everything else in the question. So, marks obtained = $$f(x)=ax-(n-x)b$$ Check if it's an injection.

$$f(x)=f(y)$$$$\implies x=y$$or$$a+b=0$$

Case $1$: $x=y \implies injection \implies n+1$ possible number of marks, since $x$ can vary from $0-n$, both inclusive.

The other case, $a+b=0$ is illogical since it implies either the marks gained or marks deducted are negative. But, even if we consider it, $$f(x)=ax+(n-x)a=an,$$ a constant. So, in this case, you'll always get the same marks!

Comment: 5 possible marks is coming as follows:(1)2 correct (2) 1 correct and 1 unattempted (3) 2 unattempted (4)1 wrong and 1 unattempted (5)2 wrong.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I forgot about the unattempted ones