# Number of possible marks that can be scored

Tags: combinatorics

In an examination of $20$ questions, for each question a student can get $-1,0,4$ marks .

Let S be set of all the marks that can received by student.
what is number of elements in S.

I defined a function of marks. Also I let no of questions of $-1$ be $a$, $0$ be $b$, $4$ be $c$.
$M= 4c-a$, $a+b+c= 20$. now at each b

$M(b=i) = 5c -20-i$, where $i$ takes integer between {0,1,...20}.

I am getting 121 answer. but answer given is $96$

Comment: @Henry could you give a hint about how you've come to these conclusions?

Comment: @maveric See here, it might be helpful: [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710881/possible-marks-in-a-mcq-test?rq=1)

Comment: @NikilKumar - all plausible negative values look easy enough.  So do all non-negative values up to seventeen $+4$s and various $0$s and $-1$s.  So you only need to check strictly between $+68$ and $+80$

Comment: @Henry could you please be slightly more elaborate? I'm confused. Why 17?

Comment: @NikilKumar With seventeen $+4$s and three $0s$ I can get to $+68$. But I can change the $0$s to one, two or three $-1$s to get $+67,+66,+65$ and I know sixteen $4$ and four $0$s gives $+64$, so I do not have problems for lower positive values

Answer (score 2):

Possible total marks range from $−20$ to $+80$ which suggests $101$ possibilities.

But $\{+79,+78,+77,+74,+73,+69\}$ are not possible, leaving $95$  possibilities

As I said in the linked question, as a more general expression, suppose that there are $n$ questions with marks $a \lt b \lt c$ and that $c-b$ and $b-a$ are coprime (in which case $c-a$ is too) and that $n \gt 2(c-a)$.  Then I think the number of different totals is $$(c-a)\left(n-\frac{c-a-3}{2}\right)$$ which in this example with $n=20, a=-1,b=0, c=+4$, gives $5 \times (20-1) = 95$, as before.  Curiously, $b$ does not appear in my expression, but is necessary for the coprime requirement

This stems from a different result saying that given two coprime positive integers $x$ and $y$ it is possible generate almost all positive integers with $ux+vy$ where $u$ and $v$ are non-negative integers, certainly all those greater than $(x-1)(y-1)$ plus half of those from $1$ through to $(x-1)(y-1)$, and then applying this at both the top and the bottom of the list